# fixed position for child elements during animation

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm working on this [codepen](https://codepen.io/w0whitaker/pen/bGRErNZ), and am a little stuck on the positioning of elements.
Essentially, I have a `div` with an inner `h2`. As it is, when clicked, the outer `div` slides to the right, bringing the `h2` with it. However, I'd like the `h2` to remain in its original position. I would have thought that `position: absolute` or `fixed` would do it, but it still moves with its parent container.

Is there a way to separate a child element from its parent container for positioning, or do I need to rethink the HTML?

```css
h2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="red" class="background-block">
  <h2>
    <!-- this content is provided by jQuery -->
  </h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the parent element to `position: relative;` and the child element to either `position: fixed;` or [`position: absolute;` with the other positioning `top: 50px; left: 0;`]. Try it if it would work.

Comment: I had to change the html to make the `div` and the `h2` siblings, and wrap them in a new parent `div`. Setting `position: relative` on that parent, and `position: absolute` on the `h2` did indeed work, so thanks!